# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'asyncio.streams'

Tags: python, django

i am working on a long project in Django and suddenly i faced this error:

```
 import asyncio
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .streams import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'asyncio.streams'
```

I tried to instal it using : pip install asyncio, But again it gave some errors :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\shutil.py", line 587, in _rmtree_unsafe
    with os.scandir(path) as scandir_it:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-ua43f6rj'
```

please Tell me how can i fix it . I am Using Python 3.8.1

Comment: This sounds like a problem with your python installation, perhaps you could reinstall python to see if that fixes the issue

Comment: thank you it worked...!!  i was actually using version 2.7 ... i uninstalled that .. and installed 3.8

Comment: please place your answer in the answer section so that i can mark it as correct.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please reinstall python3.8.1 for windows 10

Answer (score -1):

Packages and modules in python can be imported when they appear in the `PYTHONPATH` environement variable or in the `sys.path` list.

On each `PYTHONPATH` expanding, will ends up in the `sys.path` list.

so make sure that, the instalation of your `asyncio` was successeful and its path exist in the `sys.path` list. how you check? see below:

in comand line or in `script.py` type:

```
import sys
p_asyn=r'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio'
if p_asyn not in sys.path:
    print('asyncio not in the sys path list! :-(')
    sys.path.append(p_asyn)
```

its better to append new `paths` to the `PYTHONPATH` rather than editing the `sys.path`.
Anywa, if the module you are trying to import (`asuncio`) is a built in lib/module you should check if the pyhton installation was successful and the `path` environement variable edited correctly and has all `paths` that should be.

in `windows` make sure that python installation dir appears in the path. if not use the `set` command,

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\My_python_lib
```

Python usually stores its library (and thereby your site-packages folder) in the installation directory. So, if you had installed Python to C:\Python\, the default library would reside in C:\Python\Lib\ and third-party modules should be stored in C:\Python\Lib\site-packages.

This attended to `windows` users.

for further reading, enter the link here

1. [using_py2](https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html)
2. [using_py3](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html)